# Easiest porting path from OpenGL Performer?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I have an existing program written in OpenGL Performer.  Because new licences aren't available and the existing code base is old and poorly documented I was thinking about going through, fixing up the code (eliminating warnings and other bad programming practices).  As part of this process I was thinking about switching the rendering over to [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg) or [OpenSG](http://www.opensg.org/).  I am doing c++ Windows programming and would like to have the option to take advantage of quad-buffered cards to do stereo rendering.

Would it be easier to refactor my code from Performer to OpenSceneGraph or OpenSG?
Do they both support stereo rendering?
Is there some other option I should consider?
Are there any other elements I should consider in making my choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people use OpenSceneGraph, which has some heritage (developers) from Performer. My recommendation is to check the osg mailing list archives for your question, it has been discussed there.